# email crash after domain transfer

Tags: email, dns

I'm helping a friend to migrate a website to his server, however, after the domain transfer the client's emails stopped working. I believe their email was hosted on cPanel with the old provider. What does he have to do to get the emails working again? The old service hasn't been terminated yet.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information I would recommend looking into the following.

Verify the MX records are set correctly.
Verify any subdomains they are using for example mail.domain.com or imap.domain.com etc are still pointed to the proper email server.  Can verify old DNS records on previous domain server.

I would also look into the error the mail client is getting.  For example is the error an auth error, server not found or something else.

You can use online tools such as https://mxtoolbox.com/ to verify that the dns records are correct.